# Prevent system freeze when out of memory

Tags: memory-usage

So the problem is that I sometimes get memory leaks, and they sometimes leak very fast, making the system unresponsive before I can react. However, in other operating systems, even when swap is on, the system doesn't freeze entirely.

And the question is, how do I make Ubuntu behave that way, so only the problematic application freezes? An extra question: many people say SSD swap is fast enough not to freeze the system entirely. However, even if I use my SSD for swap, it freezes completely.

Comment: Ubuntu already behaves that way: The kernel includes an Out Of Memory (OOM) Killer, which automatically kills processes to save the system. Perhaps your problem is more complex.

Comment: You could try increasing the minimum free kilobytes, `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes`.